# Mysql, store options from PHP as an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue I dont exactly know how to solve. Or how to do properly, so please help me here.

Let's say you are a car store. And a customer named John want to buy a Volvo with some options like this:

```
Table name: John
Brand  |  Color          |                    Options                 |
Volvo    Green, metalic      AC, Speed control, Petrol, Sound upgrade
```

How would I store these options in Mysql as an Array so that I can get them to PHP after?
Or what is the best way to store options made by users?

Comment: You can make each option as a column of table.  If the options is too many or too different, may be you should change mysql to other nosql.

Comment: Is that a valid option? Is that a common way to store options?

Answer (score 1):

Fredrik you can use **serialize** function while storing the values in the database and **unserialize** when you want to use them. However, this makes it a little difficult to use the values with other languages, so you may consider using **json_encode()/json_decode()** functions too.

You can create a separate table for options and then link them to your main table but for your case that seems to be an overkill.

So, I guess you should be good to go with the first method.

Comment: I will take a look into serialized.
what do you think about Kevins option? About having a column for each option with a boolian connected to it?

Comment: Yes you can go with that, but that's generally preferred if you have independent keys and other columns do not depend on that or will not. So, you have to brainstorm a lot and think about all the possibilities or otherwise you could end up in a huge trouble in future.